# Ring topology support of MongoDB ReplicaSet and Sharding?

Tags: mongodb

Just curious if the following ring-like topology supported/recommended or is right for a sharded/replicaset cluster.

version: mongodb 2.4.5

hosts(all vms)

```
#[MongoDB Config]

mongodb_roles="replset1 replset2 replset3 replset4 replset5 config route"

replset1_ips="192.168.1.27 192.168.1.28"
replset1_port=27011
replset1_shard="s1"

replset2_ips="192.168.1.28  192.168.1.29"
replset2_port=27012
replset2_shard="s2"

replset3_ips="192.168.1.29 192.168.1.30"
replset3_port=27013
replset3_shard="s3"

replset4_ips="192.168.1.30 192.168.1.18"
replset4_port=27014
replset4_shard="s4"

replset5_ips="192.168.1.18 192.168.1.27"
replset5_port=27015
replset5_shard="s5"

config_ips="192.168.1.15 192.168.1.16 192.168.1.17"
config_port=20000

route_ips="192.168.1.15 192.168.1.16 192.168.1.17"
route_port=30000
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yup. I asked for this question to be migrated. Can you explain what "ring topology" means to you in this context please.? Because "Ring topolgy" is a SQL replication concept that does not really apply here.

Comment: NB: Not directly related to the topology question, but you should definitely upgrade to the latest production version for your branch of MongoDB (currently 2.4.14) as there have been a number of important bug, stability, and security fixes in the two years since 2.4.5 was released (ref: [release notes for MongoDB 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/)).

Comment: @BlakesSeven the "ring topology" means i have 5 individual servers(n1-n5) as i mentioned in my questions. When created the sharding and replicset, i tried to use  n1 with 2 for shard 1 , n2 with n3 for shard 2 , n3 with n4 for shard 3, n4 with n5 for shard 4, and n5 with n1 for shard 5. So you see it created a ring/loop from n1 to n5. The core of my questions is try to make sure this topology is not the wrong option (although i have already created this cluster in my testing environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB (as at 3.0) only supports a single primary per replica set. Replica sets can have up to 50 members, with up to 7 voting members. The 2-node replica sets you have described should have a third member (either a data-bearing secondary node or a voting-only arbiter) to allow for failover. Replica sets require a strict majority of votes (n/2+1) in order to elect and maintain a primary, so a 2 node replica set requires both members to be healthy (see: [Replica Set Elections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)).

#### Replication Topology

In terms of replication flow, the deployment of a replica set could be described as either:

1. A self-configuring [tree topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)), with the current primary as the root node. By default MongoDB allows [replication chaining](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-chained-replication/) so secondary nodes can choose to sync from other secondaries based on ping time (for example, to mitigate bandwidth usage when multiple secondaries are in a remote data centre).
2. A self-configuring [star (or hub-and-spoke) topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)), if you disable replication chaining.

You can influence selection of the current primary by configuring [member priorities](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetConfig/#replSetGetConfig.members[n].priority) for a replica set, but the general goal is to provision a set of peer nodes (with similar hardware resources such as CPU/RAM/disk) to allow any data-bearing secondary to be promoted to primary.

#### Sharded Cluster Query Topology

With a sharded cluster your application connects via the `mongos` routing service, which will [direct queries & commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) to the appropriate shard(s) and aggregate results as required. The networking topology here might be described as a partial mesh, as each `mongos` connects to the 3 config servers and the current primary for each shard (and potentially secondaries, based on [read preferences](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/)).

Note: Your approach with the use of distinct ports for different roles (replica set membership, config server, mongos) makes sense as a way to self-document the sort of service you are connecting to.